# Reassigning elements in a list using a for loop in python

Tags: python, for-loop

I'd like to know why the variables were not reassigned when I used the for loop.

```
def master_yoda(text):
    wordlist = text.split()
    for word in wordlist:
        word = word[::-1]
    return wordlist
```

Comment: The variables `wordlist` and `word` definitely were assigned. It's unclear what you mean.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

First of all when you do a slice in Python, ex:

```
// strings are basically arrays of characters
array = [1,2,3,4]
_slice = array[start:end:step]
```

It makes a COPY of the array.
Second, you are not actually referencing text, you are referencing the copy generated by `text.split()`. Do something like

```
def master_yoda(text):
  words = []
  for word in text.split():
    words.append(word[::-1])
  return words
```

Or with list comprehension:

```
def master_yoda(text):
  return [word[::-1] for word in text.split()]
```

Answer (score 0):

The variable `word` was reassigned, but if you want to change `wordlist` you need to do something like this:

```
def master_yoda(text):
    wordlist = text.split()
    for idx, word in enumerate(wordlist):
        wordlist[idx] = word[::-1]
    return wordlist
```

**EDIT** -> You could also do this:

```
def master_yoda(text):
    return text[::-1].split()[::-1]
```

Comment: Thanks David. This works well. what happens in the earlier code though? when word is reassigned, what happens to it?

Comment: @PrinceLloyd The variable `word` doesn't represent the actual value inside `wordlist`, just a copy of it, so the changes you make to `word` won't actually change `wordlist`. What happens in your code is that at the start of the `for` loop `word` is assigned to a copy of `wordlist[0]` then it is reassigned to `word[::-1]`, then, when the loop continues, it is reassigned to a copy of `wordlist[1]` and so on... All that without changing `wordlist`. Hope that explained a bit better

Comment: @PrinceLloyd I added to my answer a simpler way to achieve the same result